# ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent. If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, ssim

I am trying to calculate SSIM value for two images but I am getting error.

- `img_np.shape = (1, 256, 256)`
- `out.detach()[0].cpu().numpy().shape = (1, 256, 256)`
- `out` is the output image generated from the model

when i try to find SSIM value `ssim_ = compare_ssim(img_np, out.detach().cpu().numpy()[0])` i am having error `ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True.`

I have tried

- `ssim_ = compare_ssim(img_np, out.detach().cpu().numpy()[0], full=True)` but same error
- `ssim_ = compare_ssim(img_np, out.detach().cpu().numpy()[0], full=True, win_size=1,use_sample_covariance=False)` then i am getting output as an array not an number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shape (1, 256, 256) is interpreted as an image with 1 row, 256 columns and 256 color channels.

You may use [numpy.squeeze](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) for removing the redundant dimension:

```
img_np = np.squeeze(img_np)
```

The new shape is going to be (256, 256) - shape of a valid Grayscale image.

---

Most Python packages assumes "Channels-Last" image format.
See: [A Gentle Introduction to Channels-First and Channels-Last Image Formats](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-channels-first-and-channels-last-image-formats-for-deep-learning/).